# Unable to output the characters inside the same occurrence

Tags: java

The user will input a character that appears twice in a phrase, and I need to output the part of the phrase that is between the two occurrences of the character.  For example, if the character is `*` and the phrase is `the cow *jumped* over the moon`, the output would be `jumped`.

I got part of my code working which checks the occurrence of the character in the phrase, but I am facing the difficulty of outputting the word inside that character. Also, this has to be done only using a `for` loop.

```
char x = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
for (int y = 0; y < phrase.length(); y++) {
    char n = phrase.charAt(y);
    if (n == x)
        System.out.print(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the phrase: ");
        String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (option == 4) {
            System.out.print("Enter the character: ");
            char marker = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
            int counter = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < phrase.length(); y++) {
                if (phrase.charAt(y) == marker) {
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (counter == 1) {
                    System.out.print(phrase.charAt(y));
                } else if (counter == 2) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 4
Enter the phrase: the cow *jumped* over the moon
Enter the character: *
jumped
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is set an "is in printing state" variable to tell the code to print if it encountered the character, then stop printing once it hits the character again. There are better ways to work it, depending on what you expect the input to look like, but for clarity, let's stick to what you are trying:

```
char x = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
boolean isPrinting = false;
for (int y = 0; y < phrase.length(); y++){
    char n = phrase.charAt(y);                            
    if (n == x){
        isPrinting = !isPrinting; //start or stop printing 
    }
    else{
        //print the characters if and only if we are in 
        //a printing state and the current character is
        //not the control character
        if(isPrinting)
             System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want another way?